# Custom Vision save curent model

Tags: azure, microsoft-custom-vision

i'm using Custom vision from Microsoft service to classify image. Since the model will have to be re train few times a years, I would like to know if I can save current version of azure custom vision model to re train my new model on the same version? because  I guess microsoft will try to increase performances of its service among time so model used on this tools will probably change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the model after each run, but you cannot use an existing model as a starting point for another training run.
So yes, as it is a managed service, Microsoft might optimize or somehow change the algorithms to train in the background. It is on you to decide if that works for you. If not, a managed service like this is probably generally not something you should use, but instead train your own models entirely.